# Is every topological three-sphere conformal to the unit three-sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let's suppose we have some space M that is topologically a three-sphere (but arbitrary in specifics) with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. The affirmative solution to the Yamabe problem leads me to believe that the metric here should be conformal to the metric of a unit three-sphere centered at the origin (which we will denote $\mathbb{S}_{ab}$). In this case, we expect a relation of the form:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=|\phi|^{2}\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}$$

Suppose we now write this three-sphere as an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, we might then write then write the metric as induced:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\phi^{A}\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\phi^{B}$$

Where $\phi^{A}$ are coordinates and $\eta_{AB}$ is the flat space metric (both in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$). We might now also write the unit three-sphere metric as induced:

$$\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{A}\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\Phi^{B}$$

Where it becomes obvious that:

$$\Phi^{A}=\frac{\phi^{A}}{2|\phi^{A}|}$$

In order that $\Phi^{A}\Phi_{A}=1$. Let us try a simple substitution then:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=|\phi|^{2}\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow\phi^{A}\phi_{A}\frac{1}{4}\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\phi^{A}}{|\phi^{A}|}\right)\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\left(\frac{\phi^{B}}{|\phi^{B}|}\right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{4}\partial_{\mu}\left(\phi^{A}\right)\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\left(\phi^{B}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\phi^{A}\phi_{A}\right)^{2}\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{1}{|\phi^{A}|}\right)\partial_{\nu}\left(\frac{1}{|\phi^{B}|}\right)\right)$$

The first term is indeed the induced metric we started with, but the second term???? It simplifies a bit more:

$$=\left(\partial_{\mu}\left(\phi^{A}\right)\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\left(\phi^{B}\right)+\partial_{\mu}\left(\phi^{A}\right)\eta_{AB}\partial_{\nu}\left(\phi^{B}\right)\right)$$

This looks right except for the factor of two issue. I'm guessing I just made a mistake somewhere? so we might also say that we can choose coordinates such that:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=|\phi^{A}\phi_{A}|\frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{|\phi^{A}\phi_{A}|}=|\phi^{A}|^{2}\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Not every Riemannian metric on $S^3$ is conformal to the round metric (the metric induced from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ where $S^3$ is the unit sphere centred at the origin). Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese   Yes, this is what I'm asking. Also, I'm familiar with some of your work...it's great!!!

Comment: @Michael_Albanese.  This construction would only work if the origin is contained within the three sphere I think

Comment: Thanks. Where the origin is relative to the sphere is unimportant (you can arrange for the origin to be in the region bounded by the sphere via a translation and translations are isometries of the Euclidean metric). The problem with your approach is that an arbitrary Riemannian metric $g$ on $S^3$ is not obtained by restricting the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ to an embedding of $S^3$. Said another way, $(S^3, g)$ does not isometrically embed in $(\mathbb{R}^4, g_{\text{Eucl}})$ for all $g$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese   But can I use the Yamabe problem to say that it's conformal to the three-sphere (if we're not writing it as an induced metric)? My background is in physics, so I apologize for improper terminology.

Comment: The resolution of the Yamabe problem tells you that any metric is conformal to a metric of constant scalar curvature, but there are many of these, not just the standard one. In particular, $S^3$ admits a metric of constant negative scalar curvature.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese   apologies I must be out of my depth, I'm used to working with a spacetime where properties like scalar curvature are covariant and the three-sphere (spatially anyway) would have constant positive sectional curvature. I was looking to write an arbitrary closed spacelike foliation as a conformal transformation of a three sphere upon which I could then easily write a parallelization.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the physics setting, but it seems like your intended question is much more constrained than the one you have asked. Maybe you should ask the question on Physics SE (if you're having trouble articulating the mathematical conditions you want).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese  For the interested, I've roughly rephrased this in a simple example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612901/spin-connection-for-a-paralellization-takes-more-general-forms-than-so3-1-in   They may seem unrelated, but I assure they are not.